# Install 64-bit Chrome on 32-bit computer

Tags: google-chrome, google

Can I install 64-bit Google Chrome on 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04? My computer has 504mb RAM. The software installer is not able to install Google Chrome 64-bit version.

Answer (score 4):

You can't install any 64-bit software to a 32-bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

PC computer chips have 16 bits, 20 bits, 32 bits, 48 bits or 64 bits for addressing information.

Just as you can take a V-8 engine and stop feeding fuel to 4 cylinders to improve gas mileage you can take a 64-bit computer chip and make it behave like a 32-bit computer chip. But you can't make a 32-bit computer chip behave like a 64-bit computer chip just as you can't make a 4 cylinder engine operate as a V-8 engine for more torque and horsepower.